# Image Paging Like the iTunes App Store, in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

The specific thing I am looking at doing can be found on the App Store Application when you view an App. The screenshots of an app can be swiped from left to right to view. From what I can tell they have a UITableView with different cells holding the content. And for that one UITableViewCell where the images are Swiped left and right they use a UIScrollView with paging enabled.

I know about ScrollingMadness and the TTScrollView Classes, but both are outdated. With 3.0 the SDK can handle the problem without much code. Also my app needs to be a universal binary for iPad and iPhone so Three20 is kinda out of the question.

So my question is: Is this architecture best to solve the problem? A UITableViewCell with a UIScrollView with paging as a subview? How did Apple do it in the App Store app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the screen you are talking about is not a TableView but in fact a ScrollView. The image preview is probably another scrollview in the main scrollview or a custom view implementation. I suggest you use a scrollview and for the preview section, have a look at Apple's PageControl sample code.

Comment: These seems like one way of doing it. Unfortunately I'm deep into development and I'm using UITableView. So as a followup question how would you get the UIScroll view to be "sticky" around the area the screen shots are at. I've noticed that as I scroll to that section of the view it makes the screenshot section 100% of the height of the app.